# onclick span not working inside a button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What i want is, when click on (X) inside a button, then it should trigger the respective callback registered. But i dont know why it is failing. Below is what i tried:

**HTML**

```
<div id="cover"></div>
<template id='filtertemp'>
                <button id="filtype" class='filbut' data-filter=""></button>
</template>
<button id='create' onclick="filter();">Click</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function filter(){
var content= $('#filtertemp')[0].content;
if(content){
    var filType= content.querySelector('#filtype');
    $(filType).text("type : sometype");
    var clone= document.importNode(content,true);
    $('#cover').append($(clone));
    $('#cover > .filbut:last-child').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
}
$('.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
    alert('Remove');
});
}
```

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/wtce6dje/

I tried even below to register listener, but that too dint seemed to work:

```
$('body').on('click','.glyphicon', function(){
    alert('Remove');
});
```

Comment: works fine in shared fiddle.

Comment: Do you need this kind of things http://jsfiddle.net/wtce6dje/1/

Comment: but id should be unique

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Doesnt work for me..I am using mozilla browser

Comment: @gmo So if it doesnt works for mozilla, what can be the workaround?

Comment: Well, that depends, What's the real/initial reason why you're using a button element? And no, there's no workarround, just have to find the right element to use depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id='create' Onclick="return filter();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

having a click event within a button works for me in Chrome, but doesn't in the other browsers that I have tested.

It works when it's swapped out with a div:

```
<template id='filtertemp'>
    <div id="filtype" class='filbut' data-filter=""></div>
</template>
```